# How to automatically add attributes to specific XML elements (R or Perl or...)

Tags: xml, r, perl

I am generating SVg files from inkscape and would like to edit them automatically to add some properties to selected element in the file.

Let's say to original SVG looks like this

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" id="red-circle"/>
<circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

then I would like to find the elements having and **id** and add to these elements some other attributes such as the final xml looks like this

```
<svg height="100" width="100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" id="red-circle" new-attribute="newvalue"/>
<circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" fill="green" />
</svg>
```

I was wondering what would be the best was to automate this process (find element with tag id and add new attributes to them). I would need to do it on an important number of large SVG files, so automation is absolutely required.... I though about doing this in R or Perl, but I am open to any suggestions.

PS: The overall structure of the SVG is likely to change between documents, so I can not rely on the structure of the document to parse it. The only clue I have is that some element have an id attribute

Comment: You would usually use XSLT to do this. It is a language for transforming XML.

Comment: You can also do it quite easily with Perl and [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.45/Twig.pm).

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for the advice. Could you give and example on how to do it in this precise case? I am rather new to Perl....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are an XML::Twig version, although I find the answer of choroba quite pleasing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

# configuration
my ($infile, $id) = ('diag.svg', 'red-circle');
my ($att, $value) = ('attribute', 'value');

# processing
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    keep_spaces => 1,
    twig_handlers => {
        qq([\@id = "$id"]) => sub {
            $_->set_att($att, $value);
        },
    },
);
$twig->parsefile($infile);

# output
$twig->print;
```

Comment: you don't need the initial `//` in the handler trigger: `qq([\@id = "$id"])`. If you want to call the handler on all elements that have an `id`, you can use `qq([@id]) => ...`

Comment: @Matthias Thanks it works great! Any idea how I could retrieve the id value to re-use it in the attribute? And how to select id start by "red"?

Comment: To retrieve the id: `$_->att('id')` To select ids starting with 'red', I think you have to do the matching inside the handler.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl, using [XML::XSH2](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aXSH2), a wrapper around [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML%3a%3aLibXML):

```
open file.svg ;
for //*[@id] set @new_attribute "newvalue" ;
save :b ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In [r] the following will download a page from kbb.com, parse it for anchor tags who's `href` contains subtext `/honda/accord/` then add attribute `Fig_Vodka="Don't mind if I do"` to the XMLNodeSet of said parsed tags.

```
library(XML)
## download the webpage
kbbHTML <- readLines("http://www.kbb.com/used-cars/honda/accord/2014/private-party-value")
## parse the downloaded document to an XMLInternalDocument
kbbInternalTree <- htmlTreeParse(kbbHTML,useInternalNodes=T)
#kbbInternalTree <- htmlParse(kbbHTML, asText = TRUE) #equally valid parsed content as above
## select nodes matching our XPath expression
specific.nodes <- getNodeSet(doc = kbbInternalTree, path ="//a[contains(@href,'/honda/accord/')]")
sapply(specific.nodes, function(x) xmlAttrs(x)<-c(Fig_Vodka="Don't mind if I do"))
```

The above code adapted from [How to buy a used car with R (part 2)](http://web.stanford.edu/~knoepfle/cgi-bin/flatpress/?x=entry:entry101219-223914) and section 6.3.1 of [XML and Web Technologies for Data Sciences with R](https://books.google.com/books?id=YLS9BAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA193&dq=[r]+%22xmlAttrs%22+%22append%22&source=bl&ots=gJvT9hLwPu&sig=jwGGPdo35u6KHwjIi6GnjlUFcic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qsgeVc-BKcKCsAXOqIDoDA&output=reader&pg=GBS.PA193)

Cheers!